# why do these images not center on the webpage

Tags: html, css

I'm having some trouble centering two images under a paragraph on my website. In the image, I provided it shows the images to the far left of the window and I want to center them. I do want to note if I take out the paragraph the images center as I want but as soon as I enter in the paragraph it gets pushed to the left.

[image]

HTML

```css
.downloads-about {
  display: flex;
  height: 100vh;
}

.downloads-about img {
  height: 400px;
  width: 300px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  margin-top: 50px;
}

.container-downloads {
  max-width: 1100px;
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<section class="downloads-about">
  <div class="container-downloads">
    <h2>About</h2>
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit ametorem ipsum dolor sit amet,orem ipsum dolor sit amet,orem ipsum dolor sit amet,orem ipsum dolor sit amet,orem ipsum dolor sit amet,orem ipsum dolor sit amet,,Lorem ipsum dolor sit ametorem ipsum dolor sit amet,orem ipsum dolor
      sit amet,orem ipsum dolor sit amet,orem ipsum dolor sit amet,orem ipsum dolor sit amet,orem ipsum dolor sit amet,,
    </p>
    <img src="/imgs/Image-resizer.JPG" alt="image resizer" />
    <img src="/imgs/Image-resizer2.JPG" alt="image resizer" />
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: I'm not sure where in your CSS you've made an attempt.

Comment: You are centering `.container-downloads` not the images.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that `p` extends the element box. If you want to centralize images, you can wrap them with another div called `.box-center`, and apply flexbox styles to it.

```
    .box-center {
      display: flex; /*Apply flexbox*/
      justify-content: center; /*Centralize images*/
    }
```

```css
.downloads-about {
  display: flex;
  height: 100vh;
}

.downloads-about img {
  height: 400px;
  width: 300px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  margin-top: 50px;
}

.container-downloads {
  max-width: 1100px;
  margin: auto;
}

.box-center {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<section class="downloads-about">
  <div class="container-downloads">
    <h2>About</h2>
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit ametorem ipsum dolor sit amet,orem ipsum dolor sit amet,orem ipsum dolor sit amet,orem ipsum dolor sit amet,orem ipsum dolor sit amet,orem ipsum dolor sit amet,,Lorem ipsum dolor sit ametorem ipsum dolor sit amet,orem ipsum dolor
      sit amet,orem ipsum dolor sit amet,orem ipsum dolor sit amet,orem ipsum dolor sit amet,orem ipsum dolor sit amet,,
    </p>
    <div class="box-center">
      <img src="/imgs/Image-resizer.JPG" alt="image resizer" />
      <img src="/imgs/Image-resizer2.JPG" alt="image resizer" />
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: You're welcome!~ If you think my answer is useful, could you help to mark it as a solution to your question as well? That would help other people facing the same problem as well as giving this community and me a little support. Thank you!~ @Mendi :D